# Why is my PHP login script always return a failed login?

Tags: php, login-script

I can't figure out why `mysql_num_rows($result)` returns 0, even when the user name and password that I am inserting is correct. I have a feeling I'm missing something obvious in my code.

I am constantly getting kicked to the login failed page. Can you spot my blunder? :)

```
<?php
    // Start Session and Connect
    session_start();
    require_once('dbconnect.php');

    // Validation Errors
    $errmsg_arr = array();
    $errflag = false;

    // Connect to Database
    $link = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);
    if(!$link) {
        die('Failed to connect to server: ' . mysql_error());
    }

    $db = mysql_select_db(DB_DATABASE);
    if(!$db) {
        die("Unable to select database");
    }

    // Safety Goo.
    function clean($str) {
        $str = @trim($str);
        if(get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
            $str = stripslashes($str);
        }
        return mysql_real_escape_string($str);
    }

    $login = clean($_POST['login']);
    $password = clean($_POST['password']);

    if($login == '') {
        $errmsg_arr[] = 'Login ID missing';
        $errflag = true;
    }
    if($password == '') {
        $errmsg_arr[] = 'Password missing';
        $errflag = true;
    }

    if($errflag) {
        $_SESSION['ERRMSG_ARR'] = $errmsg_arr;
        session_write_close();
        header("location: login.php");
        exit();
    }

        $qry="SELECT * FROM members WHERE login='$login' AND passwd='".md5($_POST['password'])."'";
    $result=mysql_query($qry);


    if($result) {
        if(mysql_num_rows($result) == 1) {
            //Login Successful
            session_regenerate_id();
            $member = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
            $_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_ID'] = $member['member_id'];
            $_SESSION['SESS_FIRST_NAME'] = $member['firstname'];
            $_SESSION['SESS_LAST_NAME'] = $member['lastname'];
            session_write_close();
            header("location: member-index.php");
            exit();
        }else {
            //Login failed
            header("location: login-failed.php");
            exit();
        }
    }else {
        die("Query failed");
    }
?>
```

Comment: Dump your query as php has built it, and try it directly in mysql. Does it work?

Comment: Echo `$qry` and run it directly in mysql and see what it returns. Your code seems fine to me.

Comment: Instead of `passwd='".md5($_POST['password'])."'` <=(which is not valid), use `$password = md5($_POST['password']);` then do `passwd='".$password."'` although I don't recommend you use `md5` for password storage nor `mysql_*` functions.

Comment: Why are you passing the `$_POST['password']` as an argument to `md5()` whilst you have already sanitized it earlier ? Just try passing `$password` inside the `md5()`

Comment: your code seems fine to me too ... and please dont use mysql_* function in case you want to use php5.5 or greater

Comment: login failed means your query failed, check it by manual

Comment: `.md5($_POST['password'])` is **invalid**

Comment: Echoed $qry and it gave me what I would expect (my correct login and password). Implemented your suggestion Fred but in the end my code still kicks me out to the login failed page. A manual check of the query also returns the correct user information.

Comment: is member_id the key of $member array there ?...Then the values of the coreesponding key will be fetched from the database right ?

Comment: I consulted my friend Sean, and he was able to resolve this problem. I will post it here in case anyone is interested or has this problem in the future: "You set up the passwd row to be varchar(25).  MD5 is 32 characters in length.  Therefore, your passwords are being cut off by the table row at only 25 characters."